# Why is there no remedy available me when a manufacturer removes a feature due to a flaw after purchase?

Tags: consumer-protection

A few years ago I purchased an Intel processor simply because this has TSX features and I wanted to write code to test this feature out. They disabled this feature in a microcode update because it was buggy and they alleged they fixed this in a subsequent version of IP.

Now in the later processors this and many other so called performancec features that command a premiuim on price have been removed. I complained to intel and requested a refund and they ignored me. Is there a remedy avaiable me? And if so what is this? And why is there no compensation made for loss of enjoyment, loss of performance and nuisance caused to reimplement software when they have to clearly and publicly produced defective goods?

Comment: Consumer protection law varies greatly between jurisdictions.  Please state where you are located.  You may also want to carefully read the warranty terms you agreed to when you bought the product, and note that the warranty is almost certainly expired by now.

Comment: I guess the very general answer would be "because the manufacturer never promised to provide any such remedy in this case, and so unless there is a specific law requiring them to do so, they don't have to".  I don't think most jurisdictions have laws that are nearly so broad as requiring them to compensate for "loss of enjoyment, loss of performance and nuisance", nor even requiring them to provide refunds for more than a limited time period (usually less than "a few years").

Comment: Strange, I think that most of the Meltdown and Specter fixes were applied for chips sold from 2008. I guess they would not spend resources supporting something if it was not being used. Also chips are in use or longer these days. Twenty five years ago you used to upgrade every 3 years but now it's much longer. The lifetime of the product is different from the warranty perdiod.

Comment: Again, the question of whether they had any *legal* obligation to require such fixes might be dependent on the jurisdiction, which you still have not specified.  But they could certainly still have business reasons to do so, to placate their customers and make it more likely for them to buy more Intel products in the future.

Comment: Obligation? None. It would be negligent not to remedy the defects. So they admitted they sold defective products, that cannot be fixed, and they implement work arounds that affect the consumer detrimentally, AND you say that's fine?

Comment: It could also be that for *some* customers (who paid extra), they did make a promise of extended warranty or support, which did oblige them to provide fixes to those customers or provide some other sort of remedy.  And having developed the fixes, they released them to everyone, since that didn't cost them any extra and might buy some goodwill.

Comment: Please note that I'm not trying to take sides here; just trying to explain what the law says, as I understand it.  I get that you're unhappy with this, but I don't think that the law, as it stands, is likely to have any remedy for you.  The question of *why* you don't may really just boil down to "because your legislature did not see fit to provide one", and anything beyond that is a question for Politics.SE, not here.

Comment: So when your local authority promises to build an eight lane highway to your town, and due to some design issue they deliver one with only six working lanes, the other two being unsuable as they are deemed insecure,after a few months, there is no remedy in that case? Seriously why have we been putting up with  this for so long?

Comment: "A few years ago" is likely just too late. Even with EU consumer protection laws, "a few years" is very likely to be too late.

Answer (score 1):

Under EU consumer law, should that be your jurisdiction, you would have a claim against the seller for a full or partial refund.

Amazon was [forced to do this when Sony removed the OtherOS feature](https://www.geek.com/games/amazon-pays-partial-refund-for-ps3-sale-due-to-otheros-feature-removal-1179221/) from Playstations against the wishes of its users (users were forced to either update to continue to be able to play new games, or refuse and never receive a game update and lose the ability to play new games).

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to update the firmware if you do not want to. I'm sorry that you did not get what you wanted, but you don't have to install the updates.

The refund is normally only mandatory if the product is faulty in some way or if some other thing out of your control happened.

Comment: But it is still faulty as shipped. Would you buy a processor if you were told that TSX might cause corruption? Or would you have bought the CPU if you had known of the spectre and meltdown vulnerabilities?

Comment: How would it be faulty as shipped?

Comment: Becuase TSX bugs were discovered two generation later. The IP as shipped was defective, not fit for purpose. So you would drive a car with Takata airbags? No you'd remove them, in as much as you would take the performance hit of enabling the Spectre and Meltdown mitigations. But you would expect damages to be paid for loss of performance and resale value.

Comment: And you agreed to install the fix for that.

Comment: Which means you suffer damage because of a defective product? And you say just forgive Intel? Are they offering CPUs for free these days and making money off you data? Are you saying that I have to take whatever Intel is telling me and there is no recourse? That was the question in a nutshell.

Comment: Almost no large scale code will be flawless, they are allowed to fix it.

Comment: @RamelleBarber-Meyer: Cars are often subject to much more stringent consumer protections than other products, as well as regulations related to safety.  I am not sure that the comparison between CPUs and cars will be helpful.

Comment: Everyone has their own view on things, but I agree with Nate. Cars have tons of recalls that are not mandatory if its not a safety feature.

Comment: Do you think that it was out of the kindness of their balance sheet that Intel even bothered trying to work around the Spectre and Meltdown issues or was it the possibility of facing having to pay for damages for negligently allowing these defects, which could cause damage to customers and other parties?

Comment: Obviously they want to make money, but that doesn't mean you have to install it.